# How can I redirect URL's with commas using by htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I need to redirect urls like this one.
I would like to transform commas in dashes, how can I do this?

http://www.murrina.it/UK/cat/Murrina-Millefiori-Pendants/1,5/ -->
http://www.murrina.it/UK/cat/Murrina-Millefiori-Pendants/1-5/

I would also like that my final url will be in this way:

/en/murrina-millefiori-pendants/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*\b\d+),(\d+\b.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302]
```